# Laravel routes not working without index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel-5

I am running laravel project in wamp server.

Every time I need to add index.php to access the routes.If I try to access without index.php I get this error:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 179.
```

What I don't understand is I am running two laravel projects in this wamp server. I am facing this issue with only one laravel project and the other laravel project URLs works fine without index.php.

mod_rewrite is enabled.

my htaccess file:

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing your .htaccess with Laravel's original .htaccess? If that works, you can add your modifications 1-by-1 and see what's the problem.

Comment: This is the original .htaccess file which came with laravel. I have not edited anything.